# Easy to use file encryption software requiring only the password to decrypt

Tags: windows, encryption

I need a software to encrypt files and folders so that I can put the encrypted data on a USB drive or CD and give it to other (potentially very non-tech-savvy) people. 
To decrypt the other person should not need to install any additional software.

Required:

- Windows
- Very easy to use, especially for decrypting
- No installed software required for decryption (for example by generating an .exe that contains the files and asks for the password on double click)

Nice to have:

- Automatically generate a unique password for each encryption
- Windows explorer integration for encrypting
- Free (including for commercial use) and/or open source
- Decryption on other operating systems
- German language option

7zip self-extracting archives are very close to what I need but still a bit too complicated as it requires the user to specify a directory to extract to. Preferably it should just show its own UI and keep everything in memory without copying anything to the hard drive at all (or at least copy it to a temp folder and open it without bothering the user about it). Also the UI for encryption is a bit bloated and the lack of automatic password generation is a bummer.

I've looked at similar questions but unfortunately have not found anything exactly fitting my use case.